# How do i send more than one webhook to my twilio console

Tags: twilio

It only has one twilio webhook option for sms and voice per console it seems.  is there a work around or something through twinmil

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot add more than one Webhook URL for voice or SMS webhooks. This is because when Twilio makes a request to your webhook URL, you respond with TwiML and Twilio executes that, impacting the conversation or phone call. If you could have more than one webhook, you could provide more than one set of instructions.

If you want to send the webhook out to more URLs, you will have to create a single webhook URL that you can provide to Twilio and then forward the requests on from that endpoint.

Alternatively, you could use [Twilio Event Streams](https://www.twilio.com/docs/events) to send the data on.